# Address space layout randomization and structures in C

Tags: c, memory, struct, buffer-overflow, aslr

I have this structure:

```
struct Books {
 char  title[50];
 char  author[50];
};
```

Let's say that I know that if I pass `arg1` to the program, in some part of the code, it adds some chars in the direction `$title+52`, so the `author` value is overwritten (buffer overflow).

Now I add ASLR to my binary. By this way, some directions are random, so I think the buffer overflow that I described before could not be possible.

Is this true? Or even if I add ASLR the directions of struct members are together and buffer overflow could be possible?

Comment: ASLR randomizes the starting position of contiguous blocks of virtual memory. Your variable is still going to be inside one of those blocks. Buffer overflow problems are not going to magically go away with ASLR.

Comment: You may find this post helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3605222/what-is-address-space-layout-randomization

Comment: Note that there's a difference between "buffer overflow" as a problem, and "buffer overflow attacks."  ALSR does not address the problem of buffer overflows as bugs.  It just makes it harder to effectively use such a bug in an attack.  More specifically, it makes it harder to use such a bug to do things like steal information or gain access.  It doesn't make it much harder for an attack to crash the program.

Comment: Hi! Thanks both, I will check it:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The specific overflow you mentioned is still possible.

With the exception of bitfields, the fields of a structure follow one another in order in memory (with some possible padding in between).  This is detailed in section 6.7.2.1p15 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> **Within  a  structure  object,  the  non-bit-field  members  and  the 
>   units  in  which  bit-fields reside have addresses that increase in
>   the order in which they are declared.**  A pointer to a structure 
>   object,  suitably  converted,  points  to  its  initial  member  (or 
>   if  that  member  is  a bit-field,  then  to  the  unit  in  which  it
>   resides),  and  vice  versa.   There  may  be  unnamed padding within
>   a structure object, but not at its beginning.

So in this case the `author` field will *always* follow the `title` field, regardless of what specific address an object of type `struct Books` is located at.  The only possible difference could be the amount of padding, but unless you add or remove fields in the struct this probably won't change.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! C reference is perfect for what I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 2):

ASLR does not affect stuff that is compile-time. The compiler chooses the layout of the structure at the time of compilation and this is hardcoded in the resulting object code.

Furthermore, the C standard requires that successive struct members are laid out in memory in the order they appear in the struct definition (with unspecified padding in between members, but this too is fixed at the compilation time)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are misunderstanding the effects of ASLR (Address Space Layout Randomization): ASLR randomly arranges the positions of different virtual memory areas of a process (executable, stack, heap, data, libraries, etc) to be different in every execution. It does not change the relative position of elements in the same virtual memory area.

---

Take for example the following simple program:

```
int main(void) {
    struct {
        char a[10];
        char b[10];
    } myvar;

    printf("a: %p\n", &myvar.a);
    printf("b: %p\n", &myvar.b);

    return 0;
}
```

Here's the program's virtual memory with ASLR **disabled**:

```
0x555555554000     0x555555555000 r-xp     1000 0      /home/marco/test/test [executable segment]
0x555555754000     0x555555755000 r--p     1000 0      /home/marco/test/test [read only data]
0x555555755000     0x555555756000 rw-p     1000 1000   /home/marco/test/test [bss (global variables)]
0x7ffffffde000     0x7ffffffff000 rw-p    21000 0      [stack] <-- myvar is here
```

Output (ASLR disabled):

```
$ ./test
a: 0x7ffffffde080
b: 0x7ffffffde08a
$ ./test
a: 0x7ffffffde080
b: 0x7ffffffde08a
$ ./test
a: 0x7ffffffde080
b: 0x7ffffffde08a
```

And here's the same program with ASLR **enabled**:

```
0x559fefcbe000     0x559fefcbf000 r-xp     1000 0      /home/marco/test/test [executable segment]
0x559fefebe000     0x559fefebf000 r--p     1000 0      /home/marco/test/test [read only data]
0x559fefebf000     0x559fefec0000 rw-p     1000 1000   /home/marco/test/test [bss (global variables)]
0x7ffe3bb5e000     0x7ffe3bb7f000 rw-p    21000 0      [stack] <-- myvar is here
```

Output (ASLR enabled):

```
$ ./test
a: 0x7ffe3bb5e080
b: 0x7ffe3bb5e08a
$ ./test 
a: 0x7ff4abdeea80
b: 0x7ff4abdeea8a
$ ./test 
a: 0x7efa6b8fa080
b: 0x7efa6b8fa08a
```

---

**Your variable is still going to be inside a certain *contiguous* block of virtual memory**, and the *relative position* of the fields will not change at all. Contiguous arrays will still be contiguous using ASLR: they will just start at a different position in memory.

Since `struct` fields are by standard contiguous in memory (and follow their declaration order), this means that **buffer overflow will still be a potential problem**, even when using ASLR.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your explanation, it is very clear! Everything is undertood right now. :)